# How can I change the starting location of Google Maps showed in my website?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, web, google-maps-api-3

I have a simple Website that displays a google map. My issue is that at the minute it starts in New York and I want it to start in Lond instead. How do I that?

In my HTML page I have

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY;callback=initMap" async defer></script>` 
``
And
 `<div id="map" class="map height-400"></div>`
And I believe this is the java script it uses -

```
"use strict";

This is the gmap.js I am using which I believe picks the location. 
window.initMap = function() {
  var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType([
    {
      stylers: [
        {'saturation': -100},
        {'lightness': 50},
        {'visibility': 'simplified'}
      ]
    },
    {
      elementType: 'labels',
      stylers: [{visibility: 'on'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'road',
      stylers: [{color: '#bbb'}]
    }
  ], {
    name: 'Dublin'
  });

  var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    'img/widgets/gmap-pin.png',
    new google.maps.Size(48,54),
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(24,54)
    );

  var customMapTypeId = 'custom_style';

  var brooklyn = {lat: 41.850, lng: -73.961};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 6,
    scrollwheel: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    center: London,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, customMapTypeId]
    }
  });

  var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
    '</div>'+
    '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Brooklyn</h1>'+
    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
    '<p>277 Bedford Avenue, <br> Brooklyn, NY 11211, <br> New York, USA</p>'+
    '</div>'+
    '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString,
    maxWidth: 300
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    clickable: true,
    icon: image,
    title: 'Brooklyn',
    position: brooklyn
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  map.mapTypes.set(customMapTypeId, customMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId(customMapTypeId);
}
```

This whole API and process is very new to me and I appreciate if anyone has an answer! Ty!

Comment: `MarkerImage` is deprecated and has been removed from the documentation, use the anonymous `Icon` interface instead (probably not the issue), a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue, preferably a working [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) that reproduces your issue would be helpful.  Are you getting any JavaScript errors?

Answer (score -1):

## Center the map at the right place

You need to use a **LatLng object** to center the map at the right place.
In fact you call a missing variable "London" for center the map. set a latLng of the London place in the center argument when you initialise the map. You can try something like this :

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 6,
    scrollwheel: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    center: {lat: 51.517022, lng: -0.127011},
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
       mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, customMapTypeId]
    }
});
```

Replace just the line `center: London,` in your code by the line `center: {lat: 51.517022, lng: -0.127011},`.

## Do not share your API key

I think is very **IMPORTANT** (**very**) to not release you're apiKey on stackoverflow or any other public places.

take care at the begining of your post ( at the line `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSy... the rest of your key ... callback=initMap" async defer>`). Just replace the part coresponding to you're key by a mention like **MY_API_KEY**. I hope you have protected your key by specific domain.

## Use the documentation

The documentation of the [`Javascript Google Map API`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes?hl=fr) is really a good start. Really accessible if you have some knowledge in js, i think you can find anything you want here.